# Can android foreground services listen for key presses?

Tags: android, service, key, listener, foreground

I am trying to write a service that can listen for volume key presses but I have read somewhere that services are not supposed to react to user actions. Does that apply to foreground services as well??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Foreground services are normal services, the only difference is that those are less-likely/not killed when the system is low on memory, because the user is actively aware of them *(e.g. downloading a file with a progress indicator as a notification)*. It's only a higher priority memory wise if you will.

So yes, that applies to those as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know what music players use so the user can change the media volume even when the player activity is not in focus?

Comment: No, never had to do that. But I recommend looking at the music player source, it has to be somewhere in there. See http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/music;hb=HEAD